# Vue.js Realtime Chart with Websocket or Socket.io

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, apexcharts

I use vue.js for my project. Also I use websocket for my datas. Every one second come datas. I need to use realtime chart on my project. But I dont find any chart to solve my problem. For example I use apexchart but it have not refresh datas in my chart when new datas come.

my websocket data like:

```
{
   "topic": "2",
   "message": "data"
}
```

my database data like this:

```
  {
    "id": "1",
    "deviceName": "refrigerator",
    "deviceType": "lineChart",
    "topic": "1",
    "message": "",
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "deviceName": "refrigerator",
    "deviceType": "lineChart",
    "topic": "1",
    "message": "",
  },
```

I get my datas from database in this code. And I check my topic, is it same or not. if it is same, I put websocket message to json data to see at screen:

```
let bufferMessage = [];
   bufferMessage = jsonFromDatabase;
   socket.on("message", (topic, message) => {
       bufferMessage.forEach(element => {
       if (element.topic == topic) {
           element.message = message.toString();
       }
    });
 });
```

My code is :

```
<div id="chart">
  <apexchart type="line" height="350" :options="chartOptions" :series="$store.state.bufferMessage[index].message"></apexchart>
</div>

<script>
    import Vue from "vue";
    import ApexCharts from "apexcharts";
    import VueApexCharts from "vue-apexcharts";
    Vue.component("apexchart", VueApexCharts);
    
    export default {
      components: {
        apexchart: VueApexCharts,
      },
      data() {
        return {
          series: [
            {
              name: "Desktops",
              data: [],
            },
          ],
          chartOptions: {
            chart: {
              height: 350,
              type: "line",
              zoom: {
                enabled: false,
              },
            },
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false,
            },
            stroke: {
              curve: "straight",
            },
            title: {
              text: "Product Trends by Month",
              align: "left",
            },
            grid: {
              row: {
                colors: ["#f3f3f3", "transparent"],
                opacity: 0.5,
              },
            },
            xaxis: {
              categories: [],
            },
          },
    }
</script>
```

but the way there is no any error in this code. I just want to convert this chart to realtime chart for my websocket datas.

Comment: please include the part of your code where you try to update the data

Comment: Chart takes the datas from `series[0].data`. but my websocket datas comes from my vuex as array. I fetch my array in html codes with `v-for`. it could not run as realtime.

Comment: You say your chart takes data from `series[0].data` , but in the code above I can clearly see that your chart takes data from `$store.state.bufferMessage[index].message`. - so please include the part of the code where you try to update `$store.state.bufferMessage[index].message` .

Comment: Thanks for updating. I'm afraid at this state it's not clear to me on how your data actually looks like, that you are trying to display in the charts. In the code above the data you are trying to assing as `series` data is just a string. A string is no valid value for `series` data in the chart. You need an array of values.

Answer (score 0):

Unless OP shows the part in the code of updating the data, I only can offer a reference of the official apexcharts documentation, about updating the data :

```
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts'

export default {
 name: 'Vue Chart',
 data: function () {
  return {
   chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      id: 'vuechart-example',
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998],
    },
   },
   series: [{
    name: 'Vue Chart',
    data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70, 81]
   }]
  }
 },
 methods: {
  updateChart() {
   const max = 90;
   const min = 20;
   const newData = this.series[0].data.map(() => {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
   })
   // In the same way, update the series option
   this.series = [{
    data: newData
   }]
  }
 }
}
```

> As you can see in the example above, by just changing the props, we trigger the update event of ApexCharts. (*[from the docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/vue-charts/#)*)

> Sandbox Example https://codesandbox.io/s/50z5wrmp6k